# How to load external site to my on meteor

Tags: html, http, meteor

I am need to load external URL(for example google.com) in frame on my site.

Our site developed on Meteor. Does problem have a solution?

Comment: `<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>` ?

Comment: Do you try this solution? Google don't allow load them with frame.

Comment: then why do you say "for example"?

Comment: I meant that the url can be any

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  $("iframe").attr("src","http://google.com/");
}
```

Comment: I'll try it, but i think it doesn't work as `<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>`